# Convert Enums without knowing the type using Java Reflection API

Tags: java

I have 2 packages , A and B which contain the same list of classes. I am not able to use dozer or any mapping tool directly because the Enum values are uppercase in one package and camelcase in another package. I want to write a generic method which takes in the enum from package A and convert it into enum in package B using Reflection. Below is the specific code that I had written -

```
return a.CardType.valueOf(((b.CardType)source).getValue().toUpperCase());
```

I want to write generic code to convert assuming I have source class ( enum type) as object , source class name and destination class name

Comment: Sorry , I want to write generic code to convert assuming I have source class ( enum type) as object , source class name and destination class name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is that what you want

```
public class Mango {
    static enum Upper {A,B,C}
    static enum Lower {a,b,c}


    static <SRC extends Enum<SRC>,DST extends Enum<DST>> DST convert(SRC a, Class<DST> classDst ){
        return  Enum.valueOf(   classDst,a.name().toUpperCase());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print(convert(Lower.a,Upper.class));
    }

}
```

**EDIT:**

So you want convert lowercase/uppercase enum to camelCase? Just modify convert function to :

```
static <SRC extends Enum<SRC>,DST extends Enum<DST>> DST convert(SRC a, Class<DST> classDst ){
        for (DST dst : EnumSet.allOf(classDst)){
            if (dst.name().equalsIgnoreCase(a.name())){
                return dst;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Value not found");
    }
```

Comment: If the target is not just exactly the source in uppercase you also have the `classDst.getEnumConstants()` available for scanning.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon or you could use `EnumSet.allOf(classDst)` to verify, but if they are not same you might not get away with generic converter anyway

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry there is one challenge which I didn't notice when I posted. Enums in package A are defined in camel case.

Comment: @PunterVicky wait, are you converting from camel case   to upper/lower case, or form upper/lower case? if you convert from camelCase to uppercase then first solution will works. second solution works in both directions

Comment: I'm converting from camel case to uppercase and in the reverse direction as well. Both enum classes are in different packages.

Comment: @PunterVicky use second solution then, can be used in both directions, and you call it in same way like you call first one.